# How can I find the voltages across the diodes?

Tags: diodes

[image]
The supply voltage is 15 V and R<sub>L</sub> is 100 kΩ. Find the voltage across each diode and R<sub>L</sub>.

I<sub>s</sub> = 0.1 μA, η = 2, and V<sub>T</sub> = 25 mV.

How can I calculate the net current through R<sub>L</sub>? I have three unknowns: the net current and the voltages across the diodes.

Answer (score 5):

You'd use the Shockley equation,
$$ I(V_D)=I_S \left( e^\frac{V_D}{\eta  V_T} - 1 \right), $$
to figure it out.

You're given \$I_S\$, \$V_T\$ and \$\eta\$.

We can invert this equation: given \$I\$, solve for \$V_D\$. This will be more useful, since the current \$I\$ is the same for both diodes:

$$
V_D(I) = \ln \left( \frac{I}{I_S}+1 \right) {\eta V_T}
$$

Now, the diode D2 is in reverse saturation, since the voltage across it is on par with \$-\frac{1}{\eta V_T}\$. The reverse saturation current is then \$-I_S\$, and that diode acts as a current limiter, and sets the current in the entire circuit.

Then, the voltage drop on the resistor is \$I_S \cdot R_L\$, the voltage drop on D1 is, per Schockley equation, \$V_{D1}=\ln(2)\eta V_T\$, and the voltage drop across D2 is whatever voltage is left in the circuit.

We can simulate it and see if it agrees with our figuring:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6a9uB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diode models in the simulation have had their \$I_S\$ and \$n\equiv\eta\$ set according to the values given in the assignment. The thermal voltage is slightly different since the value used by CircuitLab is not exactly 25mV, but we see that the simulation and the computed results agree to within 1mV or so.

Answer (score 4):

The voltage across the forward-biased diode is going to be less than 0.7V (the forward voltage with substantial current). If you look at the Shockley diode equation, the current with a large negative voltage (relative to \$\eta\$ Vt) will be essentially -Is. So you can then calculate the forward voltage of the forward biased diode and the voltage across the resistor and verify that the assumptions are correct. Since RL is relatively low resistance, it will be correct. If RL was, say 1G ohm it would not be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the circuit is properly drawn and it is assembled with good parts you will not get any current flow through the circuit except for a small leakage current through the D2. D2 will have the supply dropping across it - the Vf of the first diode. There should be no voltage drop across RL other then what is caused by the leakage of D2.

Answer (score 0):

You simply solve a system with 3 uknowns.

$$
I = I_{S}\cdot\left(e^{\frac{V_{D1}}{\eta V_{T}}}-1\right),\ 
I = I_{S}\cdot\left(e^{\frac{V_{D2}}{\eta V_{T}}}-1\right),\ 
I = \frac{V_{s}-V_{D1}-V_{D2}}{R_{L}}
$$

Be careful of the sign of the voltages \$V_{D1}\$ and \$V_{D2}\$

Hint: one is <0 the other is >0.

Comment: It perhaps should be noted that "simply solving" such a system requires, generally, numerical methods, or understanding the implications of the equations to simplify them so that they'd be invertible, e.g. how I relates to Is in reverse bias, etc.

Comment: Just put it on Wolphram Alpha.

Comment: It'd improve this answer a lot if you put a link to the problem set up on Alpha, and paste the results here as well. That would then show a valuable solution technique that would be easier to follow for novices.